# Force ansible to apply changes on each lines of an inventory group

Tags: ansible, devops, ansible-inventory

I have a bare metal server, and I want to install multiple services on this server.

My inventory looks like that

```
[Mygroup]
Server port_service=9990 service_name="service1"
Server port_service=9991 service_name="service2"
```

When I launch my ansible job,only service 2 is installed because I have the same server in each line of my group. There is way to force ansible to take all lines of a group?

I don't want to create a group for each service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution is to use an alias.

This solution works fine for me

```
[Mygroup]
service_1 ansible_host=Server port_service=9990 service_name="service1"
service_2 ansible_host=Server port_service=9991 service_name="service2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Q: **"*There is a way to force Ansible to take all lines of a group?*"**

A: No. There is not. In a group, the hosts shall be unique. If there are multiple hosts with the same name the last one will be taken.

Put the variables into one line e.g.

```yaml
[Mygroup]
Server port_services="[9990, 9991]" service_names="['service1', 'service2']"
```

(and change the code).

---

See [How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html). There is a lot of other options e.g.

```yaml
[Mygroup]
Server

[Mygroup:vars]
port_services="[9990, 9991]"
service_names="['service1', 'service2']"
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got u right but this should do the trick.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html

Greets

Harry